# StringBuilder.Append for string array?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Say I have a `StringBuilder` object

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
```

And an arbritrary array of strings

```
var s = new []{"a","b","c"};
```

Is this the 'quickest' way to insert them into the `stringbuilder` instance?

```
sb.Append(string.join(string.empty, s));
```

Or does `StringBuilder` have a function I have overlooked?

Edit: Sorry I dont know how many items `sb` will contain, or how many items may be in each String[].

Comment: there are so simple, i think this isn't important

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean by "quickest" most performant than better use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArrayLen; i++)
  sb.Append(myArray[i]);
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `for (int i = 0;` ?

Comment: for is so faster than foreach or linq iterations

Comment: a for is always faster than any LINQ expression and a bit faster than a ForEach (as it goes by index instead of calling a method on IEnumerable interface)

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso, Isn't correct. Is faster to use `string.Concat` if you have array of strings.

Comment: you are right I was referring to the performance difference between LINQ and a classic for(commented by @pylover)

Comment: Can you please share ur view on why did you avoid `sb.Append(string.join(string.empty, s));` ?

Comment: Hi - by doing this you will first build up the final string (string.join) and even if this is just as fast as the direct loop (doubtful, but I did not try it) you will get the overhead of yet again copying the string into the builder - that is way the loop should be a bit faster: you don't copy quite so much strings around.

Answer (score 1):

`string.Concat(...)` should be faster than `string.Join("", ...)`. Also, this depends on what else you're doing with your `StringBuilder`. If you're only performing a few concatenations then it can be faster not to use it.

More context always helps!

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, but string.Concat is faster than StringBuilder when the strings are 4/5.
[This article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat) discuss the question very well.

Comment: It depends on what collection you pass to `Concat` method. If it is `IEnumerable<string>` then internally `Concat` uses `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score -1):

To do this in one line without a loop, you could do this:

```
sb.Append(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, s));
```

and will also work where s is any type of

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you already have the correct answer:

```
sb.Append(string.join(string.empty, s))
```